# Match 'mm/yyyy' not 'mm/dd/yyyy' using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match date using Python regular expression. I have 05/21/1990 (mm/dd/yyyy) and 01/1990 (mm/yyyy). How can I match the second one only. I tried following code

```
>>> re.search（r'\b\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}\b', '5/1/1990').group(0)
    '1/1990'
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone explain why? Isn't '\b' represent the word boundary? What is a better way to match 'mm/yyyy'?

Comment: `\b` matches the boundary between `\w` and `\W` characters. digits are `\w` characters, and `/` is a `\W` character, so `/2` counts as such a boundary.

Comment: add a sample of your text please

Comment: @Nullman I've updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Your regex suggests you want to match both `mm/yyyy` and `mm/yy` dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` matches the boundary between `\w` and `\W` characters. digits are `\w` characters, and `/` is a `\W` character, so `/2` counts as such a boundary.

You want to use a negative *lookbehind* and *lookahead* (`(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` respectively) instead:

```
(?<![/\d])\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}(?![/\d])
```

The pattern now matches one or two digits, a slash, then 2, 3 or 4 digits, provided there is no `/` or digit directly preceding and following that pattern.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?<![/\d])\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}(?![/\d])', 'Text with 05/21/1990') is None
True
>>> re.search(r'(?<![/\d])\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}(?![/\d])', 'Text with 01/1990')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 17), match='01/1990'>
```

Live demo at https://regex101.com/r/6N5wOJ/1

You probably want to narrow down the range of digits matched; you can match `99/999` with the above, which is clearly not a month/year combo. The following would narrow this down to possible month values (`01` - `12`) and years in the 20th or 21st century *only*:

```
(?<![/\d])(?:0\d|[1][012])/(?:19|20)?\d{2}(?![/\d])
```

Live demo of the latter, with some examples: https://regex101.com/r/PnatMy/1

Comment: what is the necessity of the negative lookahead ?

Comment: @marsouf: `05/21` inside `05/21/1990` would match otherwise.

Comment: @marsouf: you could easily experiment with the regex101 demo I included; try to remove the negative lookahead and see what is being matched.

Comment: isn't @Lei only interested in mm/yyyy ?

Comment: then `(?<![/\d])\d{1,2}/\d{4}` would suffice if we don't need to match mm/yy no ?

Comment: @marsouf: but then you'd not match 2-digit years, `mm/yy`.